# jquery getting value of two different sliders and perform a calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got two sliders with their own values and properties: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OZqr.gif

---

What I'm trying to do is get the values of these two sliders and perform a calculation that will be displayed next to the interest label. The calculation is: pounds*0,008*days.

---

I apologize for the messy code as I'm still a beginner.

**HTML**

```
<div class="section">
  <p>
    <label for="amount1">£</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount1" />
  </p>
  <div id="Slider1"></div>
  <p>
    <label for="amount2">Days</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount2" />
  </p>
  <div id="Slider2"></div>
  <p>
    <label for="borrow">Borrowing</label>
    <input type="text" id="borrow">

    <label for="interests">+ Interest</label>
    <input type="text" id="interests">
  </p>
  <button onClick="totalinterest()">Try</button>
  <p id="interests"></p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function getslider1(pounds) {
  $("#Slider1").slider({
    max: 400,
    min: 50,
    value: 200,
    range: false,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var pounds = $("#amount1").val(ui.value);
      $("#borrow").val(ui.value);
      return pounds;
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("amount1").textContent;
});

$(function getslider2(days) {
  $("#Slider2").slider({
    max: 30,
    min: 1,
    value: 30,
    range: false,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var days = $("#amount2").val(ui.value);
      //("#interests").val(ui.value);
      return days;
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("amount2").textContent;
});

$(function totalinterest() {
  var int = (getslider1 * 0.008);
  var tint = (int * getslider2);
  //$("#interests").val(tinterest);
  var total = tint.valueOf();
  document.getElementById("interests").innerHTML = total;
});
```

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/gsxjcqcb/ ?

Comment: Yes thank you, but i need the total to appear in the interests textbox and automatically do the calculations when the slides are changed. The button shouldn't be necessary, I just had it there when I was trying some stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi my friend.**

**Without the button Use this and the value of interests automatically do calculations**

```
$('#Slider1').mouseup(function(){
    var pounds = $( "#Slider1" ).slider( "option", "value" );
var days = $( "#Slider2" ).slider( "option", "value" );
var total= pounds*0.008*days;
      document.getElementById("interests").value = total;
    }, function(){
    var pounds = $( "#Slider1" ).slider( "option", "value" );
var days = $( "#Slider2" ).slider( "option", "value" );
var total= pounds*0.008*days;
      document.getElementById("interests").value = total;
});


$('#Slider2').mouseup(function(){
    var pounds = $( "#Slider1" ).slider( "option", "value" );
var days = $( "#Slider2" ).slider( "option", "value" );
var total= pounds*0.008*days;
      document.getElementById("interests").value = total;
    }, function(){
    var pounds = $( "#Slider1" ).slider( "option", "value" );
var days = $( "#Slider2" ).slider( "option", "value" );
var total= pounds*0.008*days;
      document.getElementById("interests").value = total;
});
```

**And if you want to use the button try this**

***HTML button***

```
<button id="btntot">Try</button>
```

***JS***

```
$('#btntot').click(function(){
    var pounds = $("#amount1").val();
  var days = $("#amount2").val();
  var total = pounds*0.008*days;
  document.getElementById("interests").value = total;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It does work with the button but I would like to try and make it work without the need of having to press a button. Is the any way to update the interests values automatically when amount1&2 are changed?

Comment: ok my frien. I update the answer and it works without the need of having to press a button.It update the interests values automatically when amount1 or 2 are changed.

Comment: I used javascript events for the slider. You can see more events here so you can see how to use some other events. http://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_events_examples.asp or https://api.jquery.com/category/events/